# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'rotate'

Tags: python, pycharm

I was creating image over text ,
Need to rotate in 360 degree ,
Got this error ,
Please help me out

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
from PIL import ImageFont, ImageOps

img = Image.open('cupcake toppe.png')


I1 = ImageDraw.Draw(img)


myFont2 = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', 15)


text2 = "3345"

img1 = text2.rotate(17.5,  expand=1)

I1.text((50, 15), text2, img1, font=myFont2, fill=(0, 0, 0))

img.show()
```

Comment: What do you expect as a result for `"3345".rotate(17.5, expand=1)`? Such a method does not exist, as the error indicates.

Comment: The `rotate` method can be invoked on PIL [Image](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html) objects, not on strings. BTW what is the point of rotating 360 degrees (per your question)?

Comment: Then, how can I rotate the string ?? Any Sugg??

Comment: Take a look at `ImageDraw.text` and indicate the appropriate text, font, and direction. See [ImageDraw](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know about this method, I hope it will help you:

The text that we will draw, and the font for it:

```
label = 'Hello'
font = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', 36)
```

For convenience, we will fix the height of the line, since `Pillow` changes it depending on the text, which may interfere with rotation. In particular, the height of the text `A` is `33 pixels`, and the height of the text `q` is already `40 pixels` due to the stick sticking down. To get the exact height of the entire string, which will fit any letters, we will use the undocumented getmetrics method for some reason:

```
line_height = sum(font.getmetrics())  # 33 + 8 = 41
```

Now we will draw the text on a separate clean image. Here we will apply a small trick: the picture will be in shades of gray and denote the alpha channel. Black (0) — full transparency, white (255) — full opacity. To make the image the size of our text, we will get its width using the getsize method, and we will take the height from our constant line_height.

```
fontimage = Image.new('L', (font.getsize(label)[0], line_height))
ImageDraw.Draw(fontimage).text((0, 0), label, fill=255, font=font)
```

Now let's turn it around. We need to add `expand=True` to increase the size of the image so that the rotated text fits.

```
fontimage = fontimage.rotate(80, resample=Image.BICUBIC, expand=True)
```

Now, we overlay the image on the original

```
orig = Image.open('original.png')
orig.paste((255, 0, 0), box=(0, 0), mask=fontimage)
```

The first argument specifies the image that we are applying. Instead, you can specify the color, which I did: this is RGB, which stands for red.

The second argument when feeding him a tuple with two elements indicates the place where the picture will be inserted.

Comment: Thank You , Now its working fine ..

Comment: how to do Center-/middle-align text , im using ( anchor="ma","mm") but its not working